# Problems With Ui.prompt & Ui.alert

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-docs

Here I tried to build the series of prompts and alerts to send SMS messages. Through this I input the values of two variables (1) mobile phone number and (2) deadline for making prepayment.

Here is its source:

```
function PromptPrepaymentReminder() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  /* Шаг № 1: ввод мобильного телефона гостя */
  var step1 = ui.prompt("Напоминание о внесении страхового депозита: шаг 1 из 3", "Введите номер мобильного телефона гостя. Например, +79522294179.", ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  var step1_button = step1.getSelectedButton();
  var recipient = step1.getResponseText();
  if (step1_button == ui.Button.OK) {
  /* Когда пользователь нажимает «Ок» на шаге № 1 */
    var step2 = ui.prompt("Напоминание о внесении страхового депозита: шаг 2 из 3", "Введите точные дату и время чтобы установить дедлайн по внесению депозита. Например, 12.06.2016, 18:00.", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    var step2_button = step2.getSelectedButton();
    var prepaymentReferenceLink = "berdyanskaya56.ru/info/prepayment";
    var prepaymentDeadline = step2.getResponseText();
    var message = "Мини-гостиница Бердянская 56. Внесение предоплаты в размере 1000 руб.: " + prepaymentReferenceLink + ". Внести необходимо до " + prepaymentDeadline + " по московскому времени.";
        if (step2_button == ui.Button.OK) {
        /* Когда пользователь нажимает «Ок» на шаге № 2 */
        var step3 = ui.alert("Напоминание о внесении страхового депозита: шаг 3 из 3", "Пожалуйста, проверьте детали СМС-напоминания перед отправкой гостю:" + "\n" + "\nНомер получателя: " + recipient + "\n" + "\nТекст оповещения: " + message, ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
        var step3_button = step3.getSelectedButton();
              if (step3_button == ui.Button.YES) {
              Logger.log("Нажал на YES на третьем шаге.");
              /* Когда пользователь нажимает «Да» на шаге № 3. Здесь же отправляем и СМС-уведомление. */
              try {
              TwilioTextMessenger(recipient, message);
              ui.alert("СМС-напоминание было успешно отправлено гостю на " + recipient + ".");
              }
              catch (err) {
              ui.alert("Не удалось отправить гостю СМС-напоминание. Пожалуйста, попробуйте снова.");
              }
              } else {
              /* Когда пользователь нажимает «Нет» на шаге № 3 */
              var step2 = ui.prompt("Напоминание о внесении страхового депозита: шаг 2 из 3", "Введите точные дату и время чтобы установить дедлайн по внесению депозита. Например, 12.06.2016, 18:00.", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
              var step2_button = step2.getSelectedButton();
              var prepaymentDeadline = step2.getResponseText();
              var message = "Мини-гостиница Бердянская 56. Внесение предоплаты в размере 1000 руб.: " + prepaymentReferenceLink + ". Внести необходимо до " + prepaymentDeadline + " по московскому времени.";
            } 
      } else if (step2_button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
      /* Когда пользователь нажимает «Отмена» на шаге № 2 */
      var step1 = ui.prompt("Напоминание о внесении страхового депозита: шаг 1 из 3", "Введите номер мобильного телефона гостя. Например, +79522294179.", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
      var step1_button = step1.getSelectedButton();
      var recipient = step1.getResponseText();
      } else if (step2_button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
      /* Когда пользователь нажимает «Закрыть» на шаге № 2 */
      ui.alert("Отправка СМС-оповещения была прервана пользователем на шаге № 2. Чтобы отправить напоминание, попробуйте повторить снова.");
      }
  } else if (step1_button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    /* Когда пользователь нажимает на «Закрыть» на шаге № 1 */
    ui.alert("Отправка СМС-оповещения была прервана пользователем на шаге № 1. Чтобы отправить напоминание, попробуйте повторить снова.");
  }
}
```

But you should pay more attention to following part:

```
/* Когда пользователь нажимает «Ок» на шаге № 2 */
            var step3 = ui.alert("Напоминание о внесении страхового депозита: шаг 3 из 3", "Пожалуйста, проверьте детали СМС-напоминания перед отправкой гостю:" + "\n" + "\nНомер получателя: " + recipient + "\n" + "\nТекст оповещения: " + message, ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
            var step3_button = step3.getSelectedButton();
                  if (step3_button == ui.Button.YES) {
                  Logger.log("Нажал на YES на третьем шаге.");
                  /* Когда пользователь нажимает «Да» на шаге № 3. Здесь же отправляем и СМС-уведомление. */
                  try {
                  TwilioTextMessenger(recipient, message);
                  ui.alert("СМС-напоминание было успешно отправлено гостю на " + recipient + ".");
                  }
                  catch (err) {
                  ui.alert("Не удалось отправить гостю СМС-напоминание. Пожалуйста, попробуйте снова.");
                  }
                  } else {
                  /* Когда пользователь нажимает «Нет» на шаге № 3 */
                  var step2 = ui.prompt("Напоминание о внесении страхового депозита: шаг 2 из 3", "Введите точные дату и время чтобы установить дедлайн по внесению депозита. Например, 12.06.2016, 18:00.", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
                  var step2_button = step2.getSelectedButton();
                  var prepaymentDeadline = step2.getResponseText();
                  var message = "Мини-гостиница Бердянская 56. Внесение предоплаты в размере 1000 руб.: " + prepaymentReferenceLink + ". Внести необходимо до " + prepaymentDeadline + " по московскому времени.";
                }
```

Above you can see that on the third step (you'll see `шаг 3 из 3` in Russian) `ui.alert` with `ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO` doesn't work in terms of the effect of pressing neither `Yes` nor `No`. Both of them makes nothing to happen while I declare two types of `ui.alert` to be displayed in each case.

Here they are in short:

```
ui.alert("СМС-напоминание было успешно отправлено гостю на " + recipient + ".");
              }
              catch (err) {
              ui.alert("Не удалось отправить гостю СМС-напоминание. Пожалуйста, попробуйте снова.");
              }
```

Here is a small lesson on how to use `ui.prompt` and `ui.alert` but it doesn't help me much :-(: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.

Please, could you check whether I miss anything here? How can I fix it to make it appear either of `ui.alert`s when the user presses `Yes` or `No`?

Comment: Just now figured out that when I replace `ui.alert` with `ui.prompt` than it works perfectly. But the matter is that I don't need extra input filed on step № 3. Just as a suggestion, can I hide it somehow?

Comment: If just commenting-out lines will do what you want, select the unnecessary lines, then type `ctrl-/` to toggle comments.

Comment: Yes, thank you sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your execution transcript: You should be getting an error from...

```
var step3_button = step3.getSelectedButton();
```

...because `step3` is a [Button](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/button.html) Enum, which does not have any method properties.

That error:

> Execution failed: TypeError: Cannot find function getSelectedButton in object YES.

Compare [`Ui.alert()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#alertprompt-buttons) to [`Ui.prompt()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#promptprompt-buttons), and you'll see that they have different Return types. If you'd used the latter, then [`PromptResponse.getselectedButton()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/prompt-response#getselectedbutton) would have been required to get the `Button`.

Just delete that problem line and replace references to `step3_button` with `step3`, and you should be fine.